# Parsing for keywords in excel using xlrd python 3.3

Tags: python, excel, parsing, xlrd

I am unfamilar with the parsing of excel files and it has come to my attention that I should use xlrd.

I wish to pull out all the line with the "predicted" keyword.

The excel array is on sheet1 it is made of 4 columns (A-D) and I need to pull columns C and D (although the whole row would work if it is easier) for the rows which contain the keyword.

The file is large over 1700 rows and is .xlsx and I am writing in Canopy Enthought using python 3.3

Thankyou for any help.

Comment: What have you tried? I charge people to write code for them. If you'd like help with existing code, that's another matter altogether.

Comment: fair enough will get back to you ASAP with the code

Answer (score 0):

The following should help to get you started:

```
import xlrd
from operator import itemgetter

keyword = "test"

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"input.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
rows = [sheet.row(row) for row in range(sheet.nrows)]   # Read in all rows

rows = [row for row in rows if keyword in ' '.join(str(col.value) for col in itemgetter(2, 3)(row))]    # Filter rows containing keyword somewhere

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

It opens the first sheet in the `xlsx` file, and creates a list containing all of the rows. For each row, it merges all of the cells together from the required columns (`C` and `D`) and checks to see if the keyword is present. If it is the row is copied. Lastly it displays all of the matching rows.

Note, the data in `rows` is still in `xlrd` format allowing you to do further processing on them.